# Python: appending to a list in a function returns no values when the list is called outside function

Tags: python, list, function, text, nltk

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I'm running into an issue where calling a list outside of the function returns empty values. What I want to do is to look at the document and if the words in that document are also in a predefined list (or not), make a list of 1s (and 0s). Next, I want to iterate through multiple documents and make a list of lists. I think the example below, in the code, will give more context to what I am trying to achieve.

**Input:**

```
import nltk
company_list = ["This is a company that does excavation",
                "Last financial quarter was bad ",
                "This year we are going be exceed the projected returns."]

middle_list = []
vector = []
final_list = []
bag = ["year", "excavation", "quarter", "returns"]


def test_function():
    counter = 0
    for company in company_list:
        tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(company)
        # eliminate the duplicates
        tokenize = set(tokenize)
        # make all the words lower case
        for word in tokenize:
            word = word.lower()
            middle_list.append(word)
        for word in bag:
            if word in middle_list:
                x = 1
            else:
                x = 0
            vector.append(x)
        # clear the middle list so that a new company's words can be put inside an empty list
        middle_list.clear()
        counter += 1
        print("Vector values: At", counter, vector)
        final_list.append(vector)
        print("List values: At", counter, final_list)
        # clear the vector so that for each company it starts with an empty list
        vector.clear()
    return final_list


test_function()
print("list outside function: ", final_list)
```

**Output:**

```
Vector values: At 1 [0, 1, 0, 0]
List values: At 1 [[0, 1, 0, 0]]
Vector values: At 2 [0, 0, 1, 0]
List values: At 2 [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
Vector values: At 3 [1, 0, 0, 1]
List values: At 3 [[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
list outside function:  [[], [], []]
```

**Expected result:** [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]

As you can see there are 2 problems:

1) When I print the list inside the function, it returns a list of vectors, but the vectors are duplicates (which I do not want)
2) When I want to print the list outside the function it returns a list of 3 lists, but each of these lists is empty.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: you have to capture the return from the function like this   final_list = test_function()

Comment: @ChristianSloper I have tried that, but the printed list (outside the function) will still return a list of empty lists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code and if you add a print just after vector.clear() I think you will see what is going on.

Final_list just contain references to vector, so when you clear this it will also clear the contents in your final_list.

change

```
final_list.append(vector)
```

to

```
final_list.append(vector.copy())
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you for taking the time to look more into it!